# How to add new types of files when using python-magic library?

Tags: python, ipython-magic

I need to use a python library for identifying the file type, and after reading the posts on this subject, [python-magic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/) seems to be what I am looking for. However, I can't find in the documentation how can I add new types of files when using this library?

There is a default set of file types - such as pdf, text, etc, but I need to be able to identify much more types than that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since python-magic is a wrapper for libmagic you would need to extend libmagic if your file types are not already identified.

Comment: OK, could you please give me a code snippet example of how to do that? (I can't seem to find any documentation on libmagic itself...)

Comment: @Clara: libmagic is free software only in alpha. Its current `README` file says "It uses the same ''magic'' databases as Ian Darwin's file(1) command as of version 3.31." The `typedef` for `struct magicentry_t` in `magic.h` looks relatively straight-forward.